# Data binding& fragment issue android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding

I'm now trying to implement data binding for a fragment in my android studio project. I followed all the guidelines provided in official android documentation.
It builds well, but when I launch it on my emulator It throw this compilation error

```
Cannot inherit from final 'com.example....databinding.FragmentFoldersBinding'
FragmentFoldersBinding()' has private access in 'com.example...databinding.FragmentFoldersBinding'`
`Cannot resolve symbol 'mAdapter'.
Cannot resolve symbol 'mViewModel'
```

Here is my fragment class code

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FoldersFragment : Fragment(), FoldersAdapter.FolderClickListener {

    private lateinit var binding : FragmentFoldersBinding

    private val vm : FoldersViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val adapter : FoldersAdapter by lazy { FoldersAdapter(this as FoldersAdapter.FolderClickListener) }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentFoldersBinding.inflate(inflater)

        binding.apply {
            viewModel = vm
            lifecycleOwner = this@FoldersFragment
            adapter = adapter
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?){

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        binding.addFolderButton.setOnClickListener {
            FolderAddDialog().show(childFragmentManager, null)
        }

        binding.foldersRecyclerView.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
        binding.foldersRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(view.context)
        vm.foldersLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            adapter.setData(it)
        }

    }

    override fun onClickedFolder(folder : Folder) {
        val action = FoldersFragmentDirections.actionFoldersFragmentToNotesFragment(folder)
        findNavController().navigate(action)
    }

    override fun setUpOnItemSwiped(swipe: SwipeCallback) {
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipe)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(binding.foldersRecyclerView)
    }

    override fun onDeleteSwiped(folder: Folder) {
        vm.deleteFolder(folder)
    }
}
```

fragment xml part

```kotlin
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example....presentation.folders_feature.FoldersViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="adapter"
            type="com.example...presentation.folders_feature.FoldersAdapter" />
    </data>
```

I've tried multiple of different solutions suggested. Thank you for helping in advance!

Comment: Adapter and viewmodel lazy init. May be when you try to apply to the binding it cause undefined.

Comment: could you also add the view model class here?